# Synchronous for-of and delay between two actions

Tags: javascript, for-loop, delay

```
let files = document.querySelectorAll('#app .File');
let downloadButton = document.querySelector('.button-download');

for (let file of files) { 
    file.click(); // click file
    setTimeout(() => {}, 1000); // delay of 1 sec between two clicks
    downloadButton.click(); // click download 
}
```

.. but it doesn't seem to work. for-of runs synchronously but it still just downloads the last file multiple times.

Comment: What did you expect to happen here? You are not `await`ing for anything, and aren't even in an `async` function. All you do is simply scheduling dry functions to all fire next second. Were you under the impression that `for of` would magically make your code understand what you expected without anything in your code telling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a "delay" function, you can create something like this:

```
function delay (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}
```

After that, all you need to do is to wrap your code in a `async` function to be able to use the `await` keyword when you call your "delay" function.

```
async function main () {
  let files = document.querySelectorAll('#app .File')
  let downloadButton = document.querySelector('.button-download')

  for (let file of files) { 
    file.click() // click file
    await delay(1000) // delay of 1 sec between two clicks
    downloadButton.click() // click download 
  }
}

main()
```